# Connect HttpResolver to API using custom port

Tags: aws-appsync

Hello: I'm creating an Appsync endpoint to gradually upgrade all of our old Rest API to GraphQL. In our API we aggregate data from some third party services (also REST).

One of those services has an endpoint running in a custom port (let's say 8050) and while our initial idea was to use Appsync HTTP Resolvers to connect to it we've been experiencing timeout problems. Our provider says there is nothing wrong with it's service but I've searched [Amazon Appsync docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/index.html) and there's nothing there about ports.

Has anyone else experienced this issue and knows how to solve it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

When configuring your HTTP Data source, you can append the port to the HTTP Endpoint URL. See below.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**As of May 2021**, I tried to specify the port number in HTTP Endpoint URL in the Data Source configuration UI, it didn't work. I still received the timeout error.

Since I have control to the HTTP API server, I changed the server to listen on port 80, removed port number from the datasource HTTP endpoint config, and things start to work. It seems as of now, appsync does not support listening on ports other than 80 for http.